# Drupal How to Log Content creators IP address

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Im creating a site that allows anonymous uploads of images. Im using drupal 7 and im almost done creating the site. I now need a way to log the ip-address of the creator of each node. is there an easy way of doing this? maybe to a hidden field?

Comment: I too am interested in knowing how to do this.  Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

When you have enabled dblog module (core), you can track most of the actions, including node creation to the database (watchdog table in the db).

I'd create a View (using Views module) to list all node creation messages to make the life easier. You can then track who created which node from which IP. That's completely up to you though.

However, note that these records gets deleted after a specific number of **total records**. You can change this value in admin settings.

Comment: How do you create a view to correlate dblog entries to a particular node?  I haven't been able to figure this out.